# Liferay: Difference between DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil and DLAppLocalServiceUtil?

Tags: liferay, document, storage, data-persistence

What is the difference between this services?

```
DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil
```

and

```
DLAppLocalServiceUtil
```

When should we use one and when the other? Is DLAppLocal a new interface in Liferay 6.1 which discourages the old DLFileEntry for application level code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> What is the difference between these services `DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil` and `DLAppLocalServiceUtil`?

`DLFileEntry` services and `DLFolderEntry` services are specifically for storing file and folder entries in liferay's database and are totally unaware of the new [repository concept](http://www.liferay.com/web/alexander.chow/blog/-/blogs/7670631) introduced in 6.1. The [user-guide](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen04-repositories-0) & this [wiki](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/CMIS+Repository) explains how to add a new repository.

Were as `DLApp` (`DLAppService` & `DLAppLocalService`) services take into account these things i.e. to say that they take care of syncing documents between liferay database and other repositories, and not just store entries in Liferay database.

The [documentation](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs-all/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/impl/DLAppLocalServiceImpl.html) for the class [`DLAppServiceImpl`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/impl/DLAppServiceImpl.java#L61) explains it all (this is almost same for [`DLAppLocalServiceImpl`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/impl/DLAppLocalServiceImpl.java#L47)), the following is an excerpt from the documentation:

> The document library local service. All portlets should interact with the document library through this class or through DLAppServiceImpl, rather than through the individual document library service classes.
>
> This class provides a unified interface to all Liferay and third party repositories. While the method signatures are universal for all repositories. Additional implementation-specific parameters may be specified in the serviceContext.
>
> The `repositoryId` parameter used by most of the methods is the primary key of the specific repository. If the repository is a default Liferay repository, the `repositoryId` is the `groupId` or `scopeGroupId`. Otherwise, the repositoryId will correspond to values obtained from [`RepositoryLocalServiceUtil`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/service/RepositoryLocalServiceUtil.java).

---

> Is DLAppLocal a new interface in Liferay 6.1?

Yes

> which discourages the old DLFileEntry for application level code?

In a sense yes, refer the above explanation. `DlAppLocalServices` is much better to use as its scope is much greater than the individual document services. Still if you want to use these interfaces for storing the documents & media from your custom plugin portlet you can go ahead and use these, I don't think there should be a problem since even `DlAppLocalServices` also internally uses the individual document services for storing in liferay repository.

Hope this provides some relevant information for your question.

Comment: Thank you, very complete!!! For the part  "... through DLAppServiceImpl, rather than individual document library service classes." I've already read, but was not sure if that meant DLFile/FolderEntryLocalServices.